# NashornScriptEngine.eval() throws exception evaluating const and arrow methods

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I am attempting to run several JavaScript files using the Nashorn API in Java. This is working great for most files, but it throws `ScriptExceptions` when a script contains the keyword `const` or when arrow methods are used. At first I was going through the files and changing these where appropriate, but it soon became apparent that several of the scripts have these statements.

Is there any way around this? I may be wrong but I think these are features exclusive to ECMAScript 6 and later. Do I need to declare that somewhere in Nashorn?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an older version of Java 8? `const` should be available as of [8u40](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/203). Other ECMAScript 6 features will be added in [coming releases](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/292).

Comment: Huh, strange. I'm running on 1.8.0_74-b02